# Any idea how to use GTK-Parasite with Go-GTK?

Tags: go, gtk

I always use [parasite](http://chipx86.github.io/gtkparasite/) when developing C GTK or Vala GTK apps. Usage is really straight forward (at least with Vala and C):

```
$ GTK_MODULES=gtkparasite app-binary
```

But I couldn't find a way to work it out with [Go-GTK](https://github.com/mattn/go-gtk) bindings. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, it didn't worked with https://github.com/mattn/go-gtk package, but turns out it worked as expected with https://github.com/conformal/gotk3:

```
$ go get -tags gtk_3_10 github.com/conformal/gotk3/gtk
```

So my advice is, for now, to switch to https://github.com/conformal/gotk3 and skip the others GTK biding packages for Go if you want to use Parasite.

Comment: Right.  Plugins for GTK 3.0 are not compatible with GTK 2.0 (what `go-gtk` uses) and vice versa.